# How it's possible to get type of generic return type

Tags: java, android, generics

I've code:

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static <T> T get() {
        ...
    }
}

void someMethod {
    String str = HelloWorld.<String>get();  
    Integer myInt = HelloWorld.<Integer>get();  
}
```

How it's possible to get a type of T inside the method get? 
getGenericReturnType & getReturnType returns me Object :( 
Is there any way to get the type of T the object in static method?
Many thanks.

Comment: Nope, it is not possible as it stands. And it wouldn't be very useful either.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible, which is why List.toArray() is so inconvenient to use.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. `get()` is a *generic method*, which means it must work for any `T` without caring, or knowing, what `T` is.

Answer (score -1):

It *is* T. No further information is available.

It's a very strange facility, which appears to me to defeat the purpose of Generics.